# UISegmentedControl not responding to interaction on Simulator

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uisegmentedcontrol, uicontrol

I have an interesting issue that I am trying to get some clarity on.

I have a `UISegmentedControl` on a view that works perfectly fine when deploying to a physical device (Switches indexes, valueChanged fires, customization set etc) but it doesn't work at all when testing on the Simulator.

When I say it doesn't work, I mean it shows up in the UI but you can't interact with it. The segments don't switch, the assigned action doesn't fire and so forth.

I am using Xcode 12.2 running on iPhone 11 sim running iOS 14.2. I've deployed to physical iPhone 11 and all works fine.

So, question is, is there a known issue with this control on simulator, have I encountered an Xcode bug, or am I just missing something basic?

**NOTE**: I've tried creating this in Storyboard and hooking up via an @IBOutlet as well as creating the full control programatically in Swift. The control shows up on simulator but can't be interacted with in both instances.

Comment: Two thoughts, neither will likely help. (And first, good details in your question.) 1.) Have you tried this on other sims beyond iPhone 11 running iOS 14.2? And 2.) Could it be something with the view hierarchy? I personally cannot use the simulator because of CoreImage limitations, but I have found that a UISegmentedControl does work as intended - at least when created in code - in past times.

Comment: Hi Paul, did you ever sort this issue as I am having the same problem. Works fine on iOS 13.* upwards until iOS 14.* I also have the same issue with `UISwitch`